# Open putty ssh-session in new Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, openssh, windows-terminal

As in the question, is it possible to open Putty session in Windows Terminal in one Window?

Or maybe there's something similar like pageant for OpenSSH?

I can create an ssh session using OpenSSH, but I need to set a passphrase for it. I don't want to do it everytime.

Comment: You can configure the optional windows feature, OpenSSH Client, to use key authentication.  How you accomplish that is documented, what phase of the configuration, are you stuck on?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `plink.exe` to start your existing putty session.

Create a new profile entry for Windows Terminal like this, where `putty-session` is the name of your putty session:

```
{
    "guid": "{141d171c-4fd9-426d-9008-8cbc4b0b05d3}",
    "name": "putty-session",
    "icon" : "ms-appx:///ProfileIcons/{9acb9455-ca41-5af7-950f-6bca1bc9722f}.png",
    "commandline": "plink.exe -load \"putty-session\""
}
```

For more details see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363597/how-to-use-a-new-windows-terminal-app-for-ssh

Comment: While this does start ssh session in Terminal, it does not work as a proper terminal you would expect from putty. For example, there's no command history by 'up' key, mc will not handle F1-10 buttons, or resize with the window, etc.

Answer (score 5):

There is a *fork* of Putty that has a robust preferences menu where you can configure it to run in windows terminal.
As documented [here](https://www.vcloudinfo.com/2019/06/putty-putty-putty-windows-terminal.html)

As far as I know, there is currently no way to enable *standard* Putty to run within Windows Terminal.

Also, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1917#issuecomment-510259173) where they explain that since Putty is actually a complete GUI application it *can't* run within Windows Terminal.

Comment: `plink[.exe]` in the standard package contains only the comms part without the GUI, and should work in Windows Terminal (it definitely does in conhost).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 how do you fix the issue with Ctrl+C, though? I.e. it should go to the remote end, but it doesn't and kills `plink` itself ... neither `-t` nor `-T` seem to make a difference. What I am trying to say is that this works for one-time commands, sure. But for interactive shell sessions?